# The view first.views.download didn't return an HttpResponse object

Tags: python, django

THis is the download view i have created.Its giving error

```
  def download(request):#Download View
    class GeneratePdf(View):
      def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
         pdf = render_to_pdf('pdf/invoice.html', data)
         return HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some syntax error. Ex: class under function. 
you can try this

```
def download(request):
    pdf = render_to_pdf('pdf/invoice.html', data)

    response = HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="mypdf.pdf"'
        return response
```